# Error at startup display.launch.py: cannot import name 'Command'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm using Jetson Nano(JP4.6) With ROS 2 Eloquent. I built Nav2 from the source code, made a test description of URDF, but could not run display.launch.py .
Here is the output I see when trying to run:

```
robot@robothost:~$ ros2 launch vector_description display.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robot/.ros/log/2022-02-18-14-13-30-610366-robothost-18354
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: cannot import name 'Command'
```

This is what the beginning looks like display.launch.py which I copied from the [tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/urdf/setup_urdf.html#build-and-launch) :

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='vector_description').find('vector_description')
    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/vector_description.urdf')
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')

robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')])}]
```

Has anyone encountered this? How can I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396370/error-at-startup-display.launch.py:-cannot-import-name-%27command%27/) by [Dr.Modi](https://answers.ros.org/users/97196/dr.modi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like Command is not in Eloquent. https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/eloquent/launch/launch/substitutions

It was added in Foxy. https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/foxy/launch/launch/substitutions/command.py

---

Originally posted by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) with karma: 166 on 2022-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0